# Footable Error:Error: No columns supplied, not showing table

Tags: jquery, css, jsp, footable

I have this table in my .jsp file:

```
<table class="footable table table-striped table-hover" id="clientTable" data-page-size="10" data-filter=#filter>
    <tbody id="idbody">
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td colspan='6'>
                    <ul class='pagination pull-right'></ul>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

which i want to fill with data from a ajax request that has this code and were i fill the table dynamically:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'GetClientSearchResultServlet',
  success: function (data) {
    var jsonString = JSON.parse(data);

    $.each(jsonString, function(k, v) {
      var $option= "<tr id='tr"+v.id+"'></tr>";
      $('#idbody').append( $option );
      $option= "<td class='client-avatar'><i class='fa fa-user'>Ola</i></td>";
      $('#tr'+v.id).append( $option );
      $option="<td><a data-toggle='tab' href='#contact-"+v.id+"' onclick=userDetail("+v.id+") class='client-link' id="+v.id+">"+v.name+"</a></td>";
      $('#tr'+v.id).append( $option );
      $option="<td>"+v.local+"</td>";
      $('#tr'+v.id).append( $option );
      $option="<td class='contact-type'><i class='fa fa-envelope'> </i></td>";
      $('#tr'+v.id).append( $option );
      $option="<td>"+v.email+"</td>";
      $('#tr'+v.id).append( $option );
      $option="<td class='client-status'><span class='label pull-right'>"+v.entityType+"</span></td>";
      $('#tr'+v.id).append( $option );
    });
  }
});
```

when i run it, it gives the error: "FooTable: unhandled error thrown during initialization. Error: No columns supplied". But if i Inspect Element on the page, the table appear in the code, with the data from my database but don't show on the page. any help?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because you don't have any table headers `<th>` defined.

Per FooTables' documentation (https://fooplugins.github.io/FooTable/docs/getting-started.html) your table should be formatted like this:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        ...
        <tr>
            <th data-breakpoints="xs">ID</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th data-breakpoints="xs">Job Title</th>
            <th data-breakpoints="xs sm">Started</th>
            <th data-breakpoints="xs sm md">DOB</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    ...
</table>
```